# How do I re-run npm build in React and Django?

Tags: reactjs, django

So I'm learning React and Django, and executed `npm run build` to run the React App in my Django server (port 8000). Then I turned the React app off(ctrl+C), and now I'm trying to run it again. So I thought I should execute `npm run build` again, but it didn't work. I have the Django server running, but I have no idea how to start the React app. 
I know this may sound unclear, but this is the best I can explain as a beginner. How do I turn the React app back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to run both of them in same port, It is better to run react by npm start, And run python.exe manage.py runserver 8080

BR